# How to get project_id and / or project_name on the test_item row

Tags: sql, reportportal

I am trying to write a sql against reportportal v5's postgresql database and discovered there is no clear way to get project_id [and by extension project_name] onto the same row as a test_item.

I initially wrote this query

```
select
    tir.result_id, 
    ti.start_time, 
    tir.end_time, 
    tir.duration, 
    ti.item_id as test_item_id, 
    cq.issue_name,
    STRING_AGG(l.log_message, '\t') as log_message 
from test_item_results tir
left join test_item ti
    on tir.result_id = ti.item_id 
left join issue i
    on tir.result_id = i.issue_id    
join (select "name", project_type, issue_type_id, issue_group_id, issue_name from project p 
        join issue_type_project itp
            on p.id = itp.project_id 
        join issue_type it 
            on itp.issue_type_id = it.id 
        where project_type = 'INTERNAL') cq
    on i.issue_type = cq.issue_type_id  
left join log l
    on tir.result_id = l.item_id
where tir.status = 'FAILED'
and type IN ('STEP')
and cq.issue_name <> 'To Investigate'
and cq.issue_name in ('Product Bug', 'Automation Bug', 'System Issue', 'No Defect')
and l.log_message is not NULL
group by tir.result_id, ti.start_time, tir.end_time, ti.item_id, tir.result_id, i.issue_id, cq.issue_name
order by ti.start_time desc
```

However, the canned failure types: Product Bug, Automation Bug, System Issue, and No Defect are available to all projects (personal or INTERNAL).  This query then leads to the same test_item and its results being duplicated across all projects.

I then looked at a db diagram and noticed that there are these empty template tables: `pattern_template_test_item` and `pattern_template`.  I have not had any success in figuring out how to use these.  I see that the `project` table has a relationship with `pattern_template` and `pattern_template` with `pattern_template_test_item` which has a relationship with `test_item`.

Any one with a clue on how to write this sql?  My end goal is to get the output I see from my query with out the duplication.  Also, I can **not** use distinct here because I need the actual project the test and result belong to.

[image]

Comment: For any `test_item` ​row, `test_item.launch_id` refers to `launch.id` and within `launch` is `launch.project_id`.  Use that to `JOIN` with your `project` to get a `project.name`.

Comment: You should resist asking more than one question at a time.  Your first question was about including project name in the result.  Ask a new question if you have other problems, like extra rows in the result you wish to avoid/suppress.  For that question, you should provide (a test case) more detail, with data and expected results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a couple of joins from `test_item` through `launch` to `project`:

```
SELECT ti.*
     , pr.name
  FROM test_item AS ti
  JOIN launch    AS la
    ON ti.launch_id = la.id
  JOIN project   AS pr
    ON la.project_id = pr.id
;
```

Just extend your current SQL to add these additional joins, as needed.

Note, however, that you used a `LEFT JOIN` when joining with `test_item`.

That suggests you might not have a matching `test_item` in every row.  You'll need to decide what you want to do in those cases.  Use outer joins if you want to keep those results with nulls instead of a project name.

Like this:

```
SELECT ti.*
     , COALESCE(pr.name, 'NoProject') AS proj_name
  FROM test_item AS ti
  LEFT JOIN launch    AS la
    ON ti.launch_id = la.id
  LEFT JOIN project   AS pr
    ON la.project_id = pr.id
;
```